# Why is node cron not running inside a forEach()?

Tags: node.js, foreach, cron, discord.js, node-cron

I'm currently creating a discord bot. One of the functions that I want it to have is to send 'scheduled messages', for which admins of that guild will be able to set the time they'll get sent.
I am using `enmap` for a per-server configuration system and `cron` for the scheduled message.
Here is my code so far:

```js
bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => {

  let banquetTime;
  banquetTime = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "banquetTime");

  cron.schedule(banquetTime, () => {

    bot.settings.ensure(guild.id, defaultSettings);
    let banquetChannel = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "banquetChannel");
    let banquetMessage = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "banquetMessage");

    guild.channels
      .find(channel => channel.name === banquetChannel)
      .send(banquetMessage)
      .catch(console.error);
  });
}, {
  scheduled: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
```

When I run this, nothing happens. Does anyone know why?

I have another function where the `.forEach()` runs INSIDE the `cron.schedule`, and it works, but I'm not sure why when the `cron.schedule` is inside `.forEach()`, it doesn't work.
Here is the code where it works:

```js
cron.schedule('00 45 12,20 * * *', () => {

  bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => {

    bot.settings.ensure(guild.id, defaultSettings);

    let expoChannel = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "expoChannel");

    let expoMessage = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "expoMessage");

    guild.channels
      .find(channel => channel.name === expoChannel)
      .send(expoMessage)
      .catch(console.error);
  });
});
```

Now, I can't run the `.forEach()` inside the cron for the top function because I need to grab the variable `banquetTime` from the `.forEach(guild)` first or else I won't be able to use it in cron.

Comment: can you `console.log(banquetTime)` before cron?

Comment: yes, it logs the 'banquetTime's from each guild. I tried just adding in numbers into the cron time instead of variable banquetTime and that doesn't even work.

Comment: id of guild is not guild name.

Comment: not sure what you mean? guild.id is working fine, it grabs the id of each guild. please elaborate

Comment: `banquetTime = bot.settings.get(guild.id, "banquetTime");` this line bro, second argument is guild id ,not name, or whatever `banquetTime` is.